# Maximal vs maximum matchings

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

Let $M_1$ be an inclusion-maximal matching in $G$ (that is, there is no matching which strictly contains it), and $M_2$ a maximum-size matching in $G$. How to prove that $|M_2| \le 2|M_1|$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $M_1$ is maximal, every edge in $M_2$ must share a vertex with an edge of $M_1$. You take it from here.